# Difference between credentials and accessKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

When creating a user and attaching it to a group with only **Programmatic access**, in the end it will provide you credentials.csv with fields

User name, Password(**empty**), Access key ID, Secret access key and Console login link

And although I did not expect it to have username, pass and link fields I can understand that it's default format.

The question is that after, you can go to security credentials tab and generate another access keys which will be different. So one user can have 2 different access keys and secret access keys? or they are different and I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So one user can have 2 different access keys and secret access keys?

Yes exactly. You might want to do this to rotate keys periodically, or to use different keys in different applications, so that you can easily disable a key without disabling all the apps you are using.

Answer (score 0):

A user can have a maximum of 2 different access/secret key pairs at any time. Nothing special about either, they both grant the same permissions that the user regularly has.